# How do output for tRESTClient

Tags: rest, output, talend

I read some param from JSON file and for each param i should send request.
That when i true move output to any element i get errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    statusCode cannot be resolved or is not a field
    string cannot be resolved or is not a field
    body cannot be resolved or is not a field
    The method getHeaders() is undefined for the type Response

    at pricing.pricing_0_1.Pricing.tFileInputJSON_1Process(Pricing.java:3334)
    at pricing.pricing_0_1.Pricing.tREST_1Process(Pricing.java:1783)
    at pricing.pricing_0_1.Pricing.runJobInTOS(Pricing.java:4634)
    at pricing.pricing_0_1.Pricing.main(Pricing.java:4366)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error messages (also having JSON files as input and output) and I found that the solution is to leave the Input, Response and Error Schema with the structures they initially had in tRESTClient. 
The Input Schema contains body and string. Here you can either use tXMLMap to define the body structure (this didn't work for me) or send the JSON file as a string with tMap directly into the tRESTClient.
The Response has the schema statusCode, body and string. Again, just retrieving the string with a tMap and tLogRow will get you the output of tRestClient.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Include the statusCode variable in the JSON

Answer (score -2):

I too got the same error, what I came across is since trestclient is expecting the schema inputs in form of stausCode , body and String.
Whereas the input is fed as key and value pair of schema. So we are getting error as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9j0o.png)

So I used a tconvertType and converted the outgoing row from tconverttype as stausCode , body and String, and it started working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n55A.png)

and all the errors went away.

Thanks,